# Handling .NET {d:"data"} JSON response with Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, .net, wcf, backbone.js

I'm using WCF to create the REST backend for an app using backbone. WCF "smartly" tries to block XSS by returning JSON with a format of {d: "data"} where data contains the actual JSON response. How can I handle this in the Backbone.sync so that I can continue to use .save, .fetch, etc and my models will be updated correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to do anything with Backbone.sync, instead just add a parse method to your models/collections  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse

```
parse: function(response) {

  return response.d;

}
```

If "data" is in fact a string, you can parse it back into JSON with:

```
parse: function(response) {

  return JSON.parse(response.d);

}
```

Not all browsers support the JSON.parse() method, so since I assume you are using jQuery, it might be safer to use `jQuery.parseJSON(response.d)` rather than `JSON.parse(response.d)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is it for the most part. However, the "data" is still considered a string rather than JSON. Example: "{\"name\":\"Joe Farmer\"}", so the name property isn't being updated from the response. Any thoughts on parsing the string back out into valid JSON so parse can return the correct response?